clang-format leave comma at beginning
We have a very large codebase from various developers. For many arguments that are written on different lines, there's several ways to do it. I want prevent code, in both styles:
    foo( arg1 /* comments here */
        arg2, // maybe even comments here
        arg3
    );

and
    foo( arg1 // comments here
        , arg2
        , arg3 // and here
    );

How can I prevend clang-format from putting the comma on its own line?
Here's my clang-format:
BasedOnStyle: Google  # Default to a style close to Astyle's "Java"
IndentWidth: 4        # Use 4 spaces for indentation
UseTab: Never         # Convert tabs to spaces
ColumnLimit: 0        # Disable line length limit (no line wrapping)

# Whitespace and Padding
SpacesInParentheses: false     # No spaces inside parentheses
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false    # No space after C-style cast
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements  # Space before parentheses in control statements (e.g., if, while)
# SpaceBeforeComma: false
# SpaceAfterComma: true          # Add padding after commas

# Pointer and Reference Alignment
PointerAlignment: Left        # Align pointer '*' with the type (similar to Astyle's --align-pointer=type)
ReferenceAlignment: Left      # Align reference '&' with the type (similar to Astyle's --align-reference=type)

# Indentation Rules
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom     # Control brace formatting specifically
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: true  # Attach braces to control statements
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: false
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  IndentBraces: false         # Don't indent braces
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true

IndentCaseLabels: true             # Indent case labels in switch statements

# Preprocessor
IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash      # Indent preprocessor directives, similar to --indent-preproc-define
SortIncludes: false

# One-liners
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline    # Keep short functions on a single line
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true          # Keep short loops on a single line
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true   # Keep short if statements on a single line
# AllowShortCompoundRequirementOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: true

# Miscellaneous
UseCRLF: true  # Use Windows line endings (CRLF)

# File-saving options
# ClangFormat doesn't have suffix or preserve date options

Edit: Here's an example:
static void Spundwand_Knicken_Beulen(
    bool bEinzelBohleSpw  // Wenn Spundwand -> Einzelbohle? (nur Text wird geändert)
    ,    int nProfile  // Anzahl der Profile (z.B. 2x HEB 300)
    ,    bool bIsSpundwand  // sonst Werte je Profil/e (HEB...)
    ,    int mode_buckling  // 0: none 1: 1993-5 (sheet piles/soldier piles) 2: 1993-1-1 (walings, frames)
    ,    LPCTSTR section_name, double A_per_prof  // [cm2/lfm]
    ,    double E  // [MN/m2]
    ,    double Iy_per_prof  // [cm4/lfm]
    ,    std::vector<GF_EC3_SteelDimensioning::MNV>& mnv, double traegerabst, double W_el_per_prof  // [cm3/lfm]
    ,    double W_pl_per_prof  // [cm3/lfm]
    ,    double b  // [mm]
    ,    double beta  // [°]
    ,    double beta_B  // [-]
    ,    double beta_D  // [-]
    ,    double delta_s_rust  // [mm]
    ,    double f_yk  // [N/mm2]
    ,    double gamma_M0, double gamma_M1, double gamma_M2, double h  // [mm]
    ,    bool is_Z  // or U
    ,    int iHohlprofil  // 0:Z,I,H,U  1:Rechteckrohr  2:Kreisrohr
    ,    double s  // [mm]
    ,    double t  // [mm]
    ,    double r1  // [mm]
    ,    double bf  // [mm] Flange width
    ,    double Delta_hw  // [m] Water level difference
    // , int iOutLanguage // 0:en, 1:de
    ,    GFString& outstring, GFXMLTree* pResults, bool& bProofsTotalOK, bool want_table_output) {
...
}

becomes
static void Spundwand_Knicken_Beulen(
    bool bEinzelBohleSpw  // Wenn Spundwand -> Einzelbohle? (nur Text wird geändert)
    ,
    int nProfile  // Anzahl der Profile (z.B. 2x HEB 300)
    ,
    bool bIsSpundwand  // sonst Werte je Profil/e (HEB...)
    ,
    int mode_buckling  // 0: none 1: 1993-5 (sheet piles/soldier piles) 2: 1993-1-1 (walings, frames)
    ,
    LPCTSTR section_name, double A_per_prof  // [cm2/lfm]
    ,
    double E  // [MN/m2]
    ,
    double Iy_per_prof  // [cm4/lfm]
    ,
    std::vector<GF_EC3_SteelDimensioning::MNV>& mnv, double traegerabst, double W_el_per_prof  // [cm3/lfm]
    ,
    double W_pl_per_prof  // [cm3/lfm]
    ,
    double b  // [mm]
    ,
    double beta  // [°]
    ,
    double beta_B  // [-]
    ,
    double beta_D  // [-]
    ,
    double delta_s_rust  // [mm]
    ,
    double f_yk  // [N/mm2]
    ,
    double gamma_M0, double gamma_M1, double gamma_M2, double h  // [mm]
    ,
    bool is_Z  // or U
    ,
    int iHohlprofil  // 0:Z,I,H,U  1:Rechteckrohr  2:Kreisrohr
    ,
    double s  // [mm]
    ,
    double t  // [mm]
    ,
    double r1  // [mm]
    ,
    double bf  // [mm] Flange width
    ,
    double Delta_hw  // [m] Water level difference
    // , int iOutLanguage // 0:en, 1:de
    ,
    GFString& outstring, GFXMLTree* pResults, bool& bProofsTotalOK, bool want_table_output) {
...
}


The question is unclear. Can you show what you want to get and what you actually get after clang-format work.

I added an example. I expect to keep my original input's line endings.
